# Compile errors on storyboard after upgrade Xcode to 6.3

Tags: storyboard, xcode6.3, ibtool

The storyboard file was previously created with Xcode6.0, after upgraded Xcode to 6.3. Compile errors jumps out with obscure error messages. I have spent hours on searching but still haven't figure out what/where exactly the problematical items are on my storyboard file.

Thanks a lot in advance for your time/suggestions, etc.

Below are the full error message:

```
    nwi_state: registration failed (1000000)
    2015-04-11 09:01:43.783 Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[11220:234260] ***storageTaskManagerExistsWithIdentifier:withIdentifier failed: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4099.)" (The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.) UserInfo=0x7ffb92e2b7b0 {NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.};
    {NSDebugDescription = "The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.";}
    nwi_state: registration failed (1000000)
    2015-04-11 09:01:55.387 Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[11225:234925] ***storageTaskManagerExistsWithIdentifier:withIdentifier failed: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4099.)" (The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.) UserInfo=0x7fac79702450 {NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.}; {
NSDebugDescription = "The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.";}
    2015-04-11 09:02:06.649 ibtoold[11212:234105] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-7531/InterfaceBuilderKit/Utilities/IBAbstractMessageChannelInterfaceBuilderToolProxy.m:38
    Details:  Failed to compile nib consisting of IBLayoutConstraint, IBLayoutConstraint, IBLayoutConstraint, IBLayoutConstraint, IBLayoutConstraint, IBLayoutConstraint, IBLayoutConstraint, IBLayoutConstraint, IBLayoutConstraint, IBLayoutConstraint, IBLayoutConstraint, IBLayoutConstraint, IBLayoutConstraint, IBLayoutConstraint, IBLayoutConstraint, IBLayoutConstraint, IBLayoutConstraint, IBLayoutConstraint, IBLayoutConstraint, IBLayoutConstraint, IBLayoutConstraint, IBLayoutConstraint, IBLayoutConstraint, IBLayoutConstraint, IBLayoutConstraint, IBLayoutConstraint, IBLayoutConstraint, IBLayoutConstraint, IBProxyObject, IBProxyObject, IBUIImageView, IBUILabel, IBUILabel, IBUITableViewCell, IBUITableViewCellContentView, and IBUITextView.

    Encountered an error communicating with Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool. If you choose to file a crash report or Radar for this issue, please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" and include their content in your crash report.

    Exception name: NSInvalidArgumentException
    Exception reason: *** +[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]: A multiplier of 0 or a nil second item together with a location for the first attribute creates an illegal constraint of a location equal to a constant. Location attributes must be specified in pairs
    Exception backtrace:
      0. CoreFoundation           0x000000010b92fc4d __exceptionPreprocess
      1. libobjc.A.dylib          0x000000010a6cebb7 objc_exception_throw
      2. CoreFoundation           0x000000010b92fb9d +
      3. Foundation               0x000000010a3f7233 VerifyConstraintArguments
      4. Foundation               0x000000010a260a5a +
      5. IBAutolayoutFoundation   0x0000000109ddaebc -
      6. IBCocoaTouchToolFoundation 0x00000001081fb977 -
      7. IBCocoaTouchToolFoundation 0x000000010821713b -
      8. IBCocoaTouchToolFoundation 0x00000001081f18b8 -
      9. IBFoundation             0x0000000109efe549 __80-[IBMessageReceiveChannel deliverMessage:toTarget:withArguments:context:result:]_block_invoke
     10. IBFoundation             0x0000000109efe2a6 -
     11. IBFoundation             0x0000000109efdf90 __88-[IBMessageReceiveChannel runBlockingReceiveLoopNotifyingQueue:notifyingTarget:context:]_block_invoke
     12. libdispatch.dylib        0x000000010eeec964 _dispatch_client_callout
     13. libdispatch.dylib        0x000000010eed9818 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke
     14. libdispatch.dylib        0x000000010eeec964 _dispatch_client_callout
     15. libdispatch.dylib        0x000000010eed7a59 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
     16. CoreFoundation           0x000000010b8971f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
     17. CoreFoundation           0x000000010b858dcb __CFRunLoopRun
     18. CoreFoundation           0x000000010b858366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
     19. Foundation               0x000000010a284f92 -
     20. IBFoundation             0x0000000109edcc20 -
     21. IBFoundation             0x0000000109edcdaf -
     22. IBFoundation             0x0000000109edd072 +
     23. ???                      0x0000000108177be7 ???
     24. libdyld.dylib            0x000000010ef1c145 start
    Exception info:{
    }

    Function: __IBAssertMarshallingFailureWithUniqueBacktrace_block_invoke
    Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fc88b104020>{number = 1, name = main}
    Hints: None
    Backtrace:
      0  0x0000000104b3f4a1 -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
      1  0x0000000104b3ec3b _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
      2  0x0000000104b3ee9e _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
      3  0x0000000105a685e8 __IBAssertMarshallingFailureWithUniqueBacktrace_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
      4  0x0000000105a68407 IBAssertMarshallingFailureWithUniqueBacktrace (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
      5  0x0000000105a6825e IBAssertMarshallingFailure (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
      6  0x000000010cd2f89a (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
      7  0x000000010cd303c9 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
      8  0x0000000105a0757c -[IBDocumentCompiler invokeWhileUsingSourceAsIntermediateDocument:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
      9  0x0000000105a0788d -[IBDocumentCompiler invokeWithIntermediateDocumentOfTargetRuntime:alwaysCopy:block:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
     10  0x000000010cd2fc97 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
     11  0x000000010cd1e0e2 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
     12  0x0000000105c19cd4 -[IBStoryboardSceneCompilationGroup compilationResultsForCompilationUnits:options:returningErrors:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
     13  0x0000000105c0aa9a -[IBStoryboardDocumentCompiler compileUnitsFromCompilationGroups:filter:options:errors:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
     14  0x0000000105c0bd73 __78-[IBStoryboardDocumentCompiler compileContentsOfStoryboardWithOptions:errors:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
     15  0x0000000105ae5f46 IBWithAutoInvalidationPool (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
     16  0x0000000105c0bb15 -[IBStoryboardDocumentCompiler compileContentsOfStoryboardWithOptions:errors:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
     17  0x0000000105c0c116 -[IBStoryboardDocumentCompiler internalCompileWithOptions:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
     18  0x000000010cd1e2f4 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
     19  0x0000000105c0ca56 __57-[IBStoryboardDocumentCompiler compileWithOptions:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
     20  0x0000000105a07699 -[IBDocumentCompiler invokeWithIntermediateDocument:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
     21  0x0000000105a0783d -[IBDocumentCompiler invokeWithIntermediateDocumentOfTargetRuntime:alwaysCopy:block:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
     22  0x0000000105c0c6fc -[IBStoryboardDocumentCompiler compileWithOptions:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
     23  0x0000000105a07a27 +[IBDocumentCompiler compileContentsOfDocument:options:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
     24  0x00000001059c2640 __47-[IBDocument compiledPackageWithOptions:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
     25  0x00000001059fafd5 -[IBDocumentAutolayoutManager assertIfArbitrationIsScheduledDuring:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
     26  0x00000001059c2597 -[IBDocument compiledPackageWithOptions:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
     27  0x0000000104947f0a (in ibtoold)
     28  0x0000000104944b40 (in ibtoold)
     29  0x0000000104947370 (in ibtoold)
     30  0x000000010494d233 (in ibtoold)
     31  0x000000010494d7b0 (in ibtoold)
     32  0x000000010494d683 (in ibtoold)
     33  0x000000010493c60a (in ibtoold)
     34  0x000000010494ce2c (in ibtoold)
     35  0x000000010494c074 (in ibtoold)
     36  0x00007fff8a78b5c9 start (in libdyld.dylib)
     37  0x0000000000000002
    Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code
```

Comment: Hi @loongman, i´m facing the same issue right now, but XCode crashes when i try to access the storyboard so i cannot do any changes on it, any ideas?

Comment: @VaroX Try Open As -> Source Code from the storyboard file menu? Then edit the storyboard (xml file) directly?

Comment: Hi @loongman, thanks for the answer. i actually did it a few minutes after i posted the comment, but it didn´t helped me at all... however, it´s known that Xcode 6.3 has some issues that need to be solved by Apple asap, until then... i´ve decided to go back to Xcode to 6.2, where everything seems to be working fine.

Comment: Hi @VaroX, thanks for the information. I probably needs to go back to Xcode6.2 as well, since there is another issue i met on Xcode6.3, the data model file can not be open.

Comment: Went back to xcode 6.2 myself and that worked... but upgraded my iphone so cant run on the device any more...

Answer (score 0):

Finally worked the problem out with an doable(although, not efficient) approach:

Narrow down scope thus to locate the problematical view scene by removing other view scenes from storyboard, in a "binary search" way.

After identified the problematical view, I re-setup the views and its constraints. Then, Build Succeeded.

Share it here for that it may be useful to somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if you try to add constraints to views that are not within the view hierachy. An auto layout restriction.

I stayed using Xcode 6.3 and did the following:

I worked out which programmatically created constraint was causing the issue (by running through the code in debug and seeing when crash occurred). Then I debugged to this point and checked neither of the 2 views within the constraint were null when the constraint was added. One of them was. I fixed this and the error went.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved the problem: I copied the storyboard file to my Windows machine and wrote a small C# program with Linq to XML to find the bogus constraint, which has the "firstItem" attribute but missing the "secondItem" attribute. Basically it is just one line:

```
        var nosecondCons = xdoc.Descendants("constraint").Where(p => p.Attribute("secondItem") == null && p.Attribute("firstItem") != null);
```